# visual studio 2008 can't open project from svn

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, devenv

I am using ankhsvn with my visual studio 2008 and when I tried to open the .sln file I get the following error:

The project file "blah blah blah" cannot be opened
The project type is not supported by this installation

Why is this???